# Delete a record from MySQL when clicking on the row in the table using DELETE method

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, ejs

How do I delete a record from MySQL database, when clicking on a row in a table generated by `ejs`.

Here is the code I use to create the table rows.

```
    <% res.forEach(function(item){ %>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><%= item.idflights %></th>
            <td><%= item.departureDate %></td>
            <td><%= item.arrivalDate %></td>
            <td><%= item.numberSeats %></td>
            <td><%= item.numberTourists %></td>
            <td><%= item.ticketPrice %></td>
        </tr>
    <% }); %>
```

Now I want to delete from my database a specific flight using the ID, but using only the `DELETE` method from `REST`.

```
app.get('/flights/deleteflight', function (req, res) {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM flights;", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render("flights/deleteflight", {res: result});
    });
});

app.delete('/flights/deleteflight', function (req, res) {
    const idflights = req.body;
    con.query("DELETE flights WHERE idflights = ?;", idflights, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

When I click on the item in the table, nothing happens. I want it to start the `app.delete()` code and delete the specific item I clicked on.

If `AJAX` code is needed, could you post how it should be written?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you _tried_ to write any AJAX? You can research it pretty easily and find examples and documentation by the thousand. These days you can use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) to make the request. What have you tried? What are you stuck on, specifically? We like to help you here, not just give you a code dump on a plate, without any apparent effort from you to begin with. We're volunteers trying to help, not a free code factory.

Comment: "When I click on the item in the table, nothing happens" ...as far as I can tell, that's because you haven't set anything up to happen. Do you understand how to attach an event handler to an element in (client-side) JavaScript? Again it's trivial to research, even if you don't know the right terminology. Once you've got that working, then you can move onto the AJAX part.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to make a request to server in order to delete the record. For this you should be using onclick event to call a function. Inside the function, you must make an ajax call to send data to server. On server side you must retrieve data properly in order to make delete request successful.

```
<% res.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <tr onclick='deleteFlight(%= item.idflights %)'>
        <th scope="row"><%= item.idflights %></th>
        <td><%= item.departureDate %></td>
        <td><%= item.arrivalDate %></td>
        <td><%= item.numberSeats %></td>
        <td><%= item.numberTourists %></td>
        <td><%= item.ticketPrice %></td>
    </tr>
<% }); %>

function deleteFlight(flightId) {
    // make ajax delete call to your server with body: { flightId: flightId }

   $.ajax({
      url: '/flights/deleteflight',
      type: 'DELETE',
      data: { flightId: flightId },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) { }
   });
}
```

On the server side:

```
app.delete('/flights/deleteflight', function (req, res) {
    const idflights = req.body.flightId;
    con.query("DELETE flights WHERE idflights = ?;", idflights, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DELETE is activated on the server and jQuery exists on the client side.
You have to change your server method to get the "id" variable from the request.

```
    // When click on delete button..
    // Get id of the item "id"

    $.ajax({
       url: '/flights/deleteflight/:id',
       type: 'DELETE',
       data: {"id": id},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
          // remove from gui or reload or something..
       }});
```

You may test to do a DELETE request using Postman for example, just to verify the server side before doing the client side. Hope this helps!